# Not working example for Dialogflow V2 api

Tags: c#, dialogflow-es

Experienced problems with C# SDK documentation which can be found here: 
http://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.V2/api/Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.V2.SessionsClient.html#Google_Cloud_Dialogflow_V2_SessionsClient_Create_Google_Api_Gax_Grpc_ServiceEndpoint_Google_Cloud_Dialogflow_V2_SessionsSettings_

No reference for method ToChannelCredentials().
We cannot connect the SDK to dialogflow, even with blank project. Is this method still existing or deprecated?

```
using Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.V2;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Grpc.Auth;
using Grpc.Core;
...
GoogleCredential cred = GoogleCredential.FromFile("/path/to/credentials.json");
Channel channel = new Channel(
    SessionsClient.DefaultEndpoint.Host, SessionsClient.DefaultEndpoint.Port, cred.ToChannelCredentials());
SessionsClient client = SessionsClient.Create(channel);
...
// Shutdown the channel when it is no longer required.
channel.ShutdownAsync().Wait();
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried connecting using the service account private key ? (**Json file**)

Follow these steps (working example in C#)

1. After you create a Dialogflow agent go to the agent's settings --> General --> click on the **Service Account** link
2. You will be sent to to google cloud platform where you can create a service account
3. After you create a service account, there will be an option to create a **KEY**, create it and download the (JSON) format of it
4. This key will be used to connect from your C# project to the Dialogflow agent
5. Install **Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.V2** package in your project
6. Create for example a Dialogflow manager class (check below for an example)

   ```
       public class DialogflowManager {
       private string _userID;
       private string _webRootPath;
       private string _contentRootPath;
       private string _projectId;
       private SessionsClient _sessionsClient;
       private SessionName _sessionName;

       public DialogflowManager(string userID, string webRootPath, string contentRootPath, string projectId) {

           _userID = userID;
           _webRootPath = webRootPath;
           _contentRootPath = contentRootPath;
           _projectId = projectId;
           SetEnvironmentVariable();

       }

       private void SetEnvironmentVariable() {
           try {
               Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", _contentRootPath + "\\Keys\\{THE_DOWNLOADED_JSON_FILE_HERE}.json");
           } catch (ArgumentNullException) {
               throw;
           } catch (ArgumentException) {
               throw;
           } catch (SecurityException) {
               throw;
           }
       }

       private async Task CreateSession() {
           // Create client
           _sessionsClient = await SessionsClient.CreateAsync();
           // Initialize request argument(s)
           _sessionName = new SessionName(_projectId, _userID);

       }

       public async Task < QueryResult > CheckIntent(string userInput, string LanguageCode = "en") {
           await CreateSession();
           QueryInput queryInput = new QueryInput();
           var queryText = new TextInput();
           queryText.Text = userInput;
           queryText.LanguageCode = LanguageCode;
           queryInput.Text = queryText;

           // Make the request
           DetectIntentResponse response = await _sessionsClient.DetectIntentAsync(_sessionName, queryInput);
           return response.QueryResult;
       }
   }
   ```
7. And then this can be called like this for example to get detect Intents

   ```
        DialogflowManager dialogflow = new DialogflowManager("{INSERT_USER_ID}",
       _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath,
       _hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath,
       "{INSERT_AGENT_ID");

   var dialogflowQueryResult = await dialogflow.CheckIntent("{INSERT_USER_INPUT}");
   ```

Comment: In your example under #7: How / Where do I instantiate `_hostingEnvironment`?

Comment: @Shiasu-sama It is injected in the constructor (DI) where i am calling DialogflowManager

Comment: What should `_contentRootPath` be set to?

Comment: Those are being used to get the actual location of the json Key file, i just noticed that webRoothPath is not used in the manager so you can disregard it, but the _contentRootPath returns the absolute path to the directory that contains the application content files