# Dialogflow .NET core, C# - detect intent not working

Tags: asp.net-core, dialogflow-es

I want to invoke DetectIntent programatically. 
I am using Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.V2 - Client libraries.

```
using Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.V2;

var query = new QueryInput
{
 Text = new TextInput
  {
    Text = text,
    LanguageCode = "en-us"
  }
};

var sessionId = "1234567890";
var agent = "myAgentName";

var creds = GoogleCredential.FromFile("JSONFileName");
Channel channel = new Channel(
SessionsClient.DefaultEndpoint.Host, SessionsClient.DefaultEndpoint.Port, creds.ToChannelCredentials());
var client = SessionsClient.Create(channel);

DetectIntentRequest request = new DetectIntentRequest
{
  SessionAsSessionName = new SessionName("smartresort-facebook-bot-fgvjh", "1111"),
  QueryInput = query,
};

DetectIntentResponse response = client.DetectIntent(request);
```

With above code I am getting error as below

[image: Error]

I am already using same JSON file in node js code and it is working fine. So in nodejs detect intent code is working fine. I am trying to do the same in .NET core.

After this I have tried another code snippet.

```
var client = SessionsClient.Create();

var response = client.DetectIntent(
    session: new SessionName("smartresort-facebook-bot-fgvjh", "1234567890"),
    queryInput: new QueryInput()
    {
       Text = new TextInput()
       {
         Text = text,
         LanguageCode = "en-us"
       }
    }
);
```

I am not trying to write fulfillment which would be called after the intent is detected. I am trying to write the code before intent is detected. So I want to give a call to detect intent and then process the response based on which intent is detected.

Answer (score 0):

Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58447825/9888221), It is an example on how to integrate **Dialogflow** with **.Net Core** based on a working sample. If you still have more questions let me know and I will be happy to help!

Comment: Thank you Marc. I have checked the link above. That example worked for me only once. I got the response from the dailogflow for detect intent.

But when I run the program again, It is giving me the same exception - Failed to connect to add addresses.

Comment: Have you checked your network if its blocking google apis ?

Comment: First time it worked. When I run the program second time it gave error. So it does not seems to be network issue