# Dialogflow - Detect Intent freezes - C#

Tags: c#, dialogflow-es

I've set up a dialogflow agent and I'm trying to write C# code to integrate with it. 
But my problem is; the code just freezes on this method: `DetectIntent`.

Here's the Google NuGet Packages I've installed on my project:

> - Google.Api.CommonProtos (v1.7.0)
> - Google.Api.Gax (v2.10.0)
> - Google.Api.Gax.Grpc (v2.10.0)
> - Google.Api.Gax.Rest (v2.10.0)
> - Google.Apis (v1.43.0)
> - Google.Apis.Auth (v1.43.0)
> - Google.Apis.Core (v1.43.0)
> - Google.Apis.Dialogflow.v2 (v1.40.2.1612)
> - Google.Apis.Storage.v1 (v1.43.0.1791)
> - Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.V2 (v1.2.0)
> - Google.Cloud.Language.V1 (v1.4.0)
> - Google.Cloud.Storage.V1 (v2.5.0)
> - Google.LongRunning (v1.1.0)
> - Google.Protobuf (v3.11.2)
> - Grpc.Auth (v1.22.1)
> - Grpc.Core (v1.22.1)
> - Grpc.Core.Api (v2.26.0)

Then I followed this link for authentication: https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production

So I've made this method:

```
public static Grpc.Core.Channel AuthExplicitForChannel(string theProjectID, string theServiceAccountJSONFilePath)
{
    GoogleCredential googleCredential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(theServiceAccountJSONFilePath).CreateScoped(LanguageServiceClient.DefaultScopes);
    Grpc.Core.Channel mainChannel = new Grpc.Core.Channel(LanguageServiceClient.DefaultEndpoint.ToString(), googleCredential.ToChannelCredentials());
    return mainChannel;
}
```

With these usings:

```
using Grpc.Auth;
using Google.Protobuf;
using Google.LongRunning;
using Google.Api.Gax;
using Google.Api.Gax.ResourceNames;
using Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.V2;
using static Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.V2.Intent.Types;
using Google.Cloud.Language.V1;
using Google.Cloud.Storage.V1;
using Google.Apis.Dialogflow.v2.Data;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Storage.v1.Data;
```

Then I followed this link: https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/quick/api#detect-intent-text-csharp

Then I made this code:

```
...

// Session
Grpc.Core.Channel mainChannel = DialogflowManipulation.AuthExplicitForChannel(projectID, serviceAccountKeyJSONFilePath);
SessionsClient mainSessionsClient = SessionsClient.Create(mainChannel);
SessionName mainSessionName = new SessionName(projectID, sessionID);

// Input
TextInput mainTextInput = new TextInput() { Text = text, LanguageCode = languageCode };
QueryInput mainQueryInput = new QueryInput() { Text = mainTextInput };

// Detect Intent
DetectIntentResponse response = mainSessionsClient.DetectIntent(mainSessionName, mainQueryInput);

...
```

I've found when looking at the Debug - Output while in debugging mode the Output prints this after / while it hangs:

> Exception thrown: 'System.MissingMethodException' in Grpc.Core.dll

Execution just hangs on that last line `.DetectIntent`.

Where am I going wrong?

Any help / advice will be appreciated.

Comment: What error are you getting ? Are you authenticating successfully ?

Comment: No error. It just hangs on that line: `...mainSessionsClient.DetectIntent(...`

Comment: The line: `SessionsClient mainSessionsClient = SessionsClient.Create(mainChannel);` runs fine. So I assume I'm authenticating successfully. Is there maybe another way I can check / test if I'm authenticating correctly?

Comment: Check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58447825/9888221 That code is tested and still working perfectly, hopefully that can help a bit

Comment: I've tried the code from your answer, but my system just loads now. It doesn't crash or throw an error it just loads. I've found this looking at the Debug - Output: `Exception thrown: 'System.MissingMethodException' in Grpc.Core.dll`

Comment: I am using Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.V2 ( 1.0.0 ) which has Grpc.Core (1.22.0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem:

The problem was the versions of the packages I had installed were not properly compatible I guess.

My **Grpc.Core** was on *(v1.22.1)* but my **Grpc.Core.Api** was on *(v2.26.0)*.
When I changed my **Grpc.Core.Api** version to *(v1.22.1)* and tried again; my system did not hang anymore and I got a response. I also did not get the Debug Output print of: `Exception thrown: 'System.MissingMethodException' in Grpc.Core.dll` anymore.

Thanks to Marc Asmar for your helpful comments and links.

Comment: Yup, we don't support gRPC 2.x yet. We're working hard on getting everything ready - I'm hoping there will be betas in February. See https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/major-version.html